# Finite maximum log-likelihood but infinite AIC (bug in R?)

Tags: r, logistic, maximum-likelihood, aic

I have a panel data set with binary dependent variable of 20,000 observations and 11 independent variables.  I ran a logistic regression with fixed effects and the model returns maximum log likelihood value of `-7417.845` and AIC equals `Inf`. I am not sure why here the AIC value goes to infinity?

I am using R package "[glmmML](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmML/glmmML.pdf)".

Comment: According to the definition of AIC, it should be $2\cdot 11 + 2\cdot 7417.845 = 14879.69$. Maybe there is something wrong with the glmmML package.

Comment: AIC is calculated by glmmML as `aic.model <- -2 * fit$loglik + 2 * nvars` (see source code) so are you sure that you are pasting the proper values in here?

Comment: I am running a fixed effects models, so the number of variables may be large, but even that I still don't know why AIC is inf?

Comment: Or is this actually a trivial question, since I can always get the AIC manually with the reported logLik value?